# Cannot see GUI when trying to install AMD Catalyst

Tags: linux-mint, amd-catalyst, fglrx

I am trying to install the [amd driver for linux](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86).When I run the .run file the GUI appears without any of the text for the widgets being available.

Comment: FYI AMD driver for Linux is buggy. At least in my case on Ubuntu 13.10 it did not work well.

Comment: @Neutralizer Ditto on Ubuntu 10.04 through 13.04. I won't be buying AMD again any time soon, and nVidia (at least back in pre-2010) was even worse. Works OK on open source drivers, but only the last couple years.

Comment: open source doesn't support full capabilities of the hardware. for example, I wanted to run WebGL which was only possible with official drivers.